# Bluetooth proximity scan while paired

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been doing a ton of research on this project I want to do, probably read every SO post (bluejacking, RFCOMM, beacons, etc...) and my head is spinning.

I want to create a system at home, using Arduino (with bluetooth le) that will scan bluetooth and detect when my phone or any of my family members phones are in proximity. Whether this is a MAC scanner or simply getting the friendly name. I would also like to get the RSSI. I dont need to do accurate distance measurement but I would like to know approximately how close they are. Does anybody have any suggestions for this approach? I know I can create an app on the phone and have it become a beacon and this may be an option but I am concerned with Android, it would have to be Marshmallow 5.0 at a minimum. I would like support to be a little lower than that, like JB or KK. So, it seems like there should be a simple scan, just looking for the MAC or name. That is all I really need.

That said, the main question I have is, can you scan for and see bluetooth devices in range if they are already paired to something? Like a Bluetooth headset? I understand bluetooth is point to point but does it allow multiple connections or at least broadcast the mac or name when paired?

This question, along with any general suggestions will help me out tremendously!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth Discovery from the Listener involves Listening for Bluetooth Inquiry packets(RX) and inquiry response (TX).if done continuously this will deplete the battery. Hence most devices (including Mobile Phones and Headsets) has a policy of when to be discover-able and connectable. Headsets in particular are discoverable only when they are instructed and connectable until one device is connected to it ( There are probably exceptions where the headset has the capability to be connected to multiple phones at the same time). Most Mobile Phones are discoverable only when they are in settings screen ( Android,IOS and Windows Phones), but unlike the headset case they are connectable.

so one option with the MobilePhone is to see if it is possible to connect to them after pairing once ( for example by trying a service search on the remote device and see if it returns the service attributes, this internally makes a connection and indirectly ensures the presence of the device).

if you are specific about a mobile phone which is already paired then you might need to establish a higherlayer connection ( such as SPP) with Authentication and encryption. This would force a two way check between devices to see whether they are already paired. other less secure option is to rely on the Phone (Android and IOS phones doesn't generally Allow a higher layer connection without encryption/pairing) and try to establish an SPP connection to the phone.

Another option is to use Bluetooth-LowEnergy. But Note that security in BT was superior to BLE till BTv4.1 and same on BTv4.2.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! This helps me understand it alot more. What if I am not worried about pairing and security though? And, I am also fine with BLE (although I need to research if BLE is currently in Android and iOS devices). Basically, if I have my arduino, with BLE and running not on a battery, constantly scanning, which I still need to figure out how to do, can I detect my phone is in range via Bluetooth. Much like you would see the SSID of the wifi when in range. I understand your comment that they are typically not discoverable. Does this change with BLE?

Comment: as i understand in Android and IOS, the Phone has to be in Bluetooth Settings screen or an Application running on the Phone which ask for LE scanning runs on the Phones , in the above two cases the Phone can detect the advertisement from the scanner otherwise the phone cannot detect the advertisement from the scanner.

Comment: The strength of the Link and Encryption Keys are very good. in BT4.2 SHA-256 ( note that there is no known instance of SHA-256 broken) is used to create the keys and AES 128 is used for encryption. Diffie–Hellman key exchange is used to securely create the keys in an insecure link.  if you are going to use BT4.1 from a security perspective  BT classic is a better alternative. but if you are going to use BT4.2 both classic and lowenergy are equally secure.